# Taking too much time to synchronize with SUP 2.1.3 using different personalization parameters

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3, sup

I am trying to develop an application in Objective C using `XCode` with `SUP 2.1.3` as back end.I am having a number of `MBOs` in the back end.Now I am using personalization parameters to synchronise with SUP.

So now I am facing a problem like to retrieve the data from different `MBOs` I have to synchronize several times using different personalisation parameters for different `MBOs`.So when I am running the  application it is taking too much time to synchronize it again and again.What should I do to avoid this?
Can I use any synchronization groups or something instead?
Can anyone please help me in solving this.I am totally new to this technology.
Thank you very much for any help in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I know this Problem, keep in mind that a new Set of Personalizationparams, did not affect a complete Deltasync, you have to fetch new Data which is referring to the new Params.

And keep also in mind, the SUP Server takes much Time for investigation of the delta.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think my problem has been solved somewhat now.What I did is,instead of 'synchronize' function I used 'synchronize:synhronizationGroup' method.It made my executions faster and avoided some exceptions too.